# Number of right inverses for surjective map between two sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, combinations, inverse

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$, $B = \{x, y, z\}$, and define $f : A → B$ by $f(1) = f(3) = f(4) = y, f(2) = f(5)=x, f(6) = f(7) = z.$ How many functions $g : B → A$ satisfy $f ◦ g = id_B$?

This is example of right inverse.

Would the answer be one, as there is fixed value of surjective function $f$ given. And there is no free element in set B left.

The hint given is : answer depends on $f$, not just the sizes of sets $A,B$.
Am not sure what that means

Had there been asked to compute all possible right inverses for a given function f, then the answer would be $1$ again.

However, if can have choice of function $f$, then the possible right inverses are: 
Each element in set A can map to only one element. So, each has a choice of $m$ ($|B|= m, |A|= n$).
Hence, $n^m$ choices available.

Comment: "Had there been asked to compute all possible right inverses, then the answer would be based on just the available choices to map in the set B for elements in set A." No. That's incorrect. And note that you cannot talk about "right inverses" in a vacuum. You can only talk about right inverses *of a particular function*.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so that is what the hint means. I hope my edited post is correct.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin also the same restriction should exist on left inverse too, i.e. we talk about left inverses of a particular function.

Comment: No, that's not what the hint is talking about. It's what the term **means**. The hint is there because in the [other problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4427269/742) that you likewise mangled, the answer depends only on the sizes of $A$ and of $B$, and not on the particular function: all injective functions from $A$ to $B$ have the same number of left inverses, and that number can be computed from the sizes of $A$ and $B$. But the number of right inverses of a particular surjective function from $A$ to $B$ depends not just on the sizes of $A$ and $B$, but also on the function.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin would be highly thankful if your last comment is an answer, as would cover both inverses.

Comment: That comment does not provide an answer to either question. If you believe it does, then you are still confused.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin only your detailed answer then can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

I don't think the hint given is very well worded, and seems to be what's confusing you.  Since the function $\ f\ $ you're given is completely specified, it doesn't seem to me to be of much help to be told that your answer should depend on $\ f\ $.  Of course it should, because you'll have to make use of the given definition of $\ f\ $ to count the number of $\ g$s that could be a right inverse of it.

The required condition,  $\ f\circ g=id_B $, will be satisfied if and only if
$$
f(g(x))=x, f(g(y))=y,\ \text{ and}\ f(g(z))=z\ .
$$
So what are the possible values of $\ g(x)\ $?  It can't be $\ 1\ $ or $\ 6\ $, for instance, because $\ f(1)=y\ne x\ $ and $\ f(6)=z\ne x\ $.  It *could* be *either* $\ 2\ $ *or* $\ 5\ $, however, because $\ f(2)=f(5)=x\ $.

Comment: How right inverse differs from left inverse, when anyway no map (function) can be from one object, in one set, to multiple objects in other set.

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not this is a question.  When the specified codomain of a function is the same as its range it will always have a right inverse. If its range is a *strict* subset of a specified codomain, however, it can't have a right inverse.  You could restate this as saying that a function has a right inverse if and only if it is surjective.  On the other hand,  it will have a left inverse if and only if it is one-to-one—that is, if and only if it is injective.

Comment: Then left inverse differs from right inverse in that (due to restriction of injective or one-to-one map) can have function /map $g()$ applied first.